# Variables in Spring MVC servlet context?

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc, environment-variables, servletconfig

For Spring MVC project, I want to reduce errors and the amount of time when switching servers, paths, and etc in the servlet context.

Is there a way to store variables in the servlet context (i.e. `servlet-context.xml`)?

**Example**

VARIABLE is used to to switch the server url, user, and password in myDataSource

```
VARIABLE = "GOOGLE" // Server type: GOOGLE, YAHOO, BING. This will switch the server url, user, and password in myDataSource

<beans:bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.sqlserver.driver}" />
    <beans:property name="url" value="${jdbc.**VARIABLE**.url}" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="${jdbc.**VARIABLE**.user}" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="${jdbc.**VARIABLE**.pw}" />
</beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but my answer to

> Is there a way to store variables in the servlet context (i.e.
>   servlet-context.xml)?

is "No". These context configuration files are meant to be static.

What you should do instead is use Profiles. See [here](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/) and [here.](http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-spring-profiles-xml)

Answer (score 0):

The way of implementing it in XML is modifying the `web.xml` and `servlet-context.xml`.

**Solution:**

In `web.xml` add a new `context-param` for `spring.profiles.active`. This will be used as the profile selector.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>DEV-PROFILE</param-value><!-- profile name goes here -->
</context-param>
```

In the `servlet-context.xml` you'll wrap the beans with the profile. Here, I'm giving a Development and Test profile for each database connection.

```
<beans:beans profile="DEV-PROFILE">
    <beans:bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.sqlserver.driver}" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="${jdbc.dev.url}" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="${jdbc.dev.user}" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="${jdbc.dev.pw}" />
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
<beans:beans profile="TEST-PROFILE">
    <beans:bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.sqlserver.driver}" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="${jdbc.test.url}" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="${jdbc.test.user}" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="${jdbc.test.pw}" />
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

At this point beans defined after the profile beans caused errors. Thus, I had to move the java beans to a new file and imported them before the profile definitions.

```
<beans:import resource="servlet-beans.xml"/>
```